# Integrating the complex function $f(z) = x^2 + iy^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Suppose $f(z) = x^2 + iy^2$ (where $z = x + iy$ ) and consider
$C:z(t) = t + it,0 \leq t \leq 1$

Evaluate
$\int_{C} f(z)dz$

I have tried solving this,
I know that
$\int_{C} f(z)dz = \int_a^b f(z(t))z'(t)dt$ for $a \leq t \leq b$

From $z(t)$ I can easily get $z'(t)$
But I struggle to obtain $f(z(t))$ because $f(z)$ is not expressed in terms of z.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Note that $f(x+iy)=x^2+iy^2$. What do you have for
$
f(t+it)
$?

Comment: I think its $f(t + it) = t^2 + it^2$ thank you. Can't believe it was that easy

Answer (score 1):

When someone writes $f(z) = x^2 + iy^2$ is is usually understood that $z = x + yi$, i.e. $x$ is the real part of $z$ and $y$ is the imaginary part of $z$.

So if $z = t +it$, can you find the real and imaginary parts of $z$?

Comment: I believe you are asking for the real and imaginary parts of $f(z)$. I believe its $f(z) = t^2 + it^2$